# How to get meta data?

Tags: javascript, metadata, meta-tags, meta

What I am trying to do is get a certain meta.

Looking for or something similar:

```
<meta name="age" data-userid="number">

var meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
var id = meta.substring(34, 37);
console.log(id);
```

I am trying to get the  `data-userid` value. The other questions do *not* help because they are only asking how to get the `content` of the meta.

Edit:

my code from one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730897/how-to-get-meta-data/64731016#64731016) (still doesn't work):

```js
var idl = localStorage.getItem("id");
if (typeof idl !== 'undefined' && idl !== null){}else if (typeof idl == 'undefined' || idl == null){
    localStorage.removeItem("id");

    var meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];
    var idget = meta.getAttribute("data-userid");
    var id = idget;
    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getAttribute()` method in the specific element to retrieve values.

```js
var meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
console.log(meta[0].getAttribute("data-isunder13"));
```

```html
<meta name="age" data-isunder13="some value">
```

Comment: When trying this out on a real webpage, it returned `null`. But when running the snippet here, it worked.. Would I need to change the index?

Comment: My bad! I was using "age" for an example but when I typed it, I didn't change it. Haha!

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple meta tags in a page,
you should add another parameters such as name in this case to uniquely identify element you are looking for,

You can use `dataset` to get a data value:

```js
const value=document.querySelector('meta[name="age"]').dataset.isunder13;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<meta name="age" data-isunder13="false">
```

Comment: When running this on a real webpage, it would return `NaN`.

Comment: @bloke Could you console log `document.querySelectorAll('meta[name="age"]')` in your page and check number of elements and the index of one you are looking for.

Comment: The index I am looking for is 8.

Comment: Is the page live ao we can look into, or can you make a fiddle if possible?

Comment: Try with `document.querySelector('meta[name="age"][data-userid]')`

Answer (score 1):

```
//Using JS
var meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];
console.log(meta.getAttribute("data-isunder13"));

//Using JQuery
var data = $('meta[name=age]').attr('data-isunder13');
console.log(data);
```

```js
//Using JS
var meta = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];
console.log(meta.getAttribute("data-isunder13"));

//Using JQuery
var data = $('meta[name=age]').attr('data-isunder13');
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="age" data-isunder13="false">
```